# Any browser that doesn't cause noisy fan noise when playing youtube videos?

Tags: video, browser, fan

I am using Firefox in Linux. Whenever I play YouTube videos on my 4K LCD laptop screen or on an external 4K TV, I hear noisy fan noise. Switching between Intel HD iGPU and Nvidia 1050 Ti GPU is the same. What are the causes? Codec issue? Any browser that does not cause noisy fan?

Comment: The cause is 4k videos are resource demanding. I doubt it has anything to do with browsers or codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Anything task that is resource demanding like playing videos on a 4K screen or using the Nvidia 1050 Ti discrete graphics processor causes the computer to heat up, so the fans have to work harder to keep the computer cool. When the fans work harder they make more noise. Using a different web browser than Firefox won't make much of a difference in how much CPU and GPU resources the computer uses to perform these tasks.

Removing dust from the cooling fins underneath the fan might help to reduce the noise. If you listen carefully you can tell whether a loud fan noise is being caused by normal rapid spinning of the fan or by rattling or grating of the fan's bearings. If the fan noise is much too loud, then it's time to replace the fan. It's easier to replace the fan on desktop computers than it is to replace the fan on laptops, because on desktop computers the fans are easier to get at.

Comment: I just bought my brand new Thinkpad three weeks ago. There is no dust visible to me.